# Error "Invalid number format for port number"

Tags: oracle, jdbc, java-8, java-7, ojdbc

I have a project made with JDK 7 with ojdbc6 working normally. After update for JDK 8 (and recreate jar), the project raise the error "Invalid number format for port number" on connect to database. The old jar still working. Nothing was altered in source. I try update for ojdbc7, without success. The connection string is in format jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:1521:db

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where you able to reproduce that behavior at small scale, on some sample program short enough to be displayed here ?

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help in debugging this, as well as any stack trace or related code.